# How can I show a text has been copied?

Tags: android, eclipse, user-interface, copy

I wrote a text/number on a button "Text here". When I click it, it must show another text (copied) in the same page for a while .. that means I have the "Text here" copied .. how can I do it? Or what is it called? Does anybody knows?

Here is the XML but in Java, I do not know how to call it

```
 <Button
   android:text="012345"/>
```

This is of a picture of how it looks
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use inside ActionListener
`Toast.makeText(this,"Copied",1000).show();`

use : this ( if in the activity )

use : getBaseContext() ( any other place )

Comment: 1000 != 1 second - check the [Toast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html) documentation.